# Automate Selenium Test cases using Windows Service

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, windows-services

I have created a test automation solution using selenium webdriver. Now I want to execute them everyday at particular point of time . For this , I want to create a windows service which starts the tests execution without any input from my side. How should I proceed to achieve that.??
Thanks.

Comment: Is this for a company or a home grown project? If it is for a company, you should think about how you store your test results. Should everyone have access. Will this project grow further with more tests? If so you should install a Jenkins Server.

Answer (score 0):

write a batch script that keeps on running and triggers your test everyday at particular time. Or a more professional way is to use Jenkins : )

or you can also use Scheduled Tasks a windows feature 
[For details on Scheduled tasks](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000785.htm)